# Altering a List in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a problem in python were I have a list of lists. It looks like the following:

```
   [[bob, masters, 1], [sheila, brown, 9], [jack,hardy,15], [bob, masters, 
   41], [mike,benson, 21], [jack, hardy, 100]]
```

What I am trying to accomplish is convert this list of lists into a list of lists of lists(not sure that is the correct terminology). So I want my new or altered list to look like this:

```
   [[[bob, masters, 1],[bob, masters, 41]], [[sheila, brown, 9]], 
   [[jack,hardy,15], [jack, hardy, 100]],[[mike,benson, 21]]]
```

So to sum it up I want to make a list for each person's list inside of one big list.

I'm new to python so I don't know what the best route I can take is. When I read in each line and add it to the original list I use the split function which turns it into the list of lists I showed up top. If anyone could point me in the right the direction that would be helpful. I'm not sure if I should change the list I already have made, or change the way I make the list when I read the text from the file. 
Here is the code I currently have that makes my list of lists:

```
   f = open("input.txt", "r")
   inputText = []
   i = 0
   # adds each line of input file to a list
   for line in f:
      inputText.insert(i, line.split())
       i = i+1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why are you creating a `list of list of list` I think the better approach would be `list of dict` and dict would list of tuple. `{key:[(),()]}`

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new list and use a groupby function:

```
import collections

def groupby(iterable, key_fn):
    grouped = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for item in iterable:
        key = key_fn(item)
        grouped[key].append(item)
    return grouped

input_list = [['bob', 'masters', 1], ['sheila', 'brown', 9], ['jack','hardy',15], ['bob', 'masters',
   41], ['mike','benson', 21], ['jack', 'hardy', 100]]
grouped = groupby(input_list, lambda item: item[0])
final_result = list(grouped.values())
print(final_result)
```

Which outputs

```
[[['bob', 'masters', 1], ['bob', 'masters', 41]], [['sheila', 'brown', 9]], [['jack', 'hardy', 15], ['jack', 'hardy', 100]], [['mike', 'benson', 21]]]
```

Comment: perfect this is what I was looking for. I'm still a bit confused on how the list works. If I want to access the 1 out of the first bob, masters list how would I accomplish that. I thought it would be something like final_result[][][] with different values in the brackets to get a specific element but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you want to use both first and last name to group by, you will have to use `lambda item: (item[0], item[1])`. Otherwise all "bob" persons will be grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file looks something like this:

```
bob masters 1
sheila brown 9
jack hardy 15
bob masters 41
mike benson 21
jack hardy 100
```

You might want to use an intermediary `dict`:

```
data_dict = {}
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        first_name, last_name, number = line.split()
        if not (first_name, last_name) in data_dict:
            data_dict[(first_name, last_name)] = []
        data_dict[(first_name, last_name)].append(number)
```

At this point, `data_dict` looks like this:

```
{('bob', 'masters'): ['1', '41'], ('sheila', 'brown'): ['9'], ('jack', 'hardy'): ['15', '100'], ('mike', 'benson'): ['21']}
```

You can then always convert this to your desired `list` structure:

```
data_list = []
for (first_name, last_name), numbers in data_dict.items():
    data_list.append([])
    for number in numbers:
        data_list[-1].append([first_name, last_name, number])
```

So you have `data_list`:

```
[[['bob', 'masters', '1'], ['bob', 'masters', '41']], [['sheila', 'brown', '9']], [['jack', 'hardy', '15'], ['jack', 'hardy', '100']], [['mike', 'benson', '21']]]
```